# Cast from generic array to my class?

Tags: java

I have a generic class, `SimpleStack<T>`, which contains these methods:

```
private T[] stack;

public T[] getStack() {
    return this.stack;
}

public boolean add(T item) {
    boolean filled = isFull();
    if (!filled) {
        stack[size()] = item;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    for (T item : stack) {
        if (item != null) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I'm trying to use this class to act as a `Profile` class, and I've filled the array `stack` with `Profile` objects. However, when I try to return this array, it says that it can't cast from `Object` to `Profile`.

Here's a snippet from where I fill the array, inside my main method:

```
SimpleStack<Profile> profiles = new SimpleStack<Profile>(50);
Profile profile = new Profile();
profiles.add(profile);
```

I try to call the getter to return the array, and cast it to a `Profile[]`. This is what fails:

```
Profile[] tempStack = Arrays.copyOf(profiles.getStack(), (profiles.getStack()).length, Profile[].class);
```

I've tried it several ways, but the ultimately all do the same thing (attempt to cast the generic array to `Profile[]`).

Does anyone know what I've done wrong? I can provide more code if necessary. I tried to take the relevant bits.

Comment: How are you initializing the array `stack`?

Comment: @Codebender
I create stack like this:

`stack = (T[]) new Object[size];`

Comment: Please include the stack trace or compiler error you're getting.  In general, arrays and generics don't mix; you'd be much better off replacing this with a `List`.

Comment: Make `getStack` return `Object[]`. (Also you may or may not want to stop pretending it's a `T[]`, since that *only* works as a result of a "bug" in the generics system)

Comment: Don't return the array. Don't expose implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you initialize it. See [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) for more details.

```
public class SimpleStack<T> {
    private final T[] stack;

    public SimpleStack(Class<T[]> clazz, int size) {
        this.stack = clazz.cast(Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType(), size));
    }

    public T[] getStack() {
        return stack;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SimpleStack<Profile> profiles = new SimpleStack<>(Profile[].class, 50);
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        Profile[] array = profiles.getStack();
    }

    public static class Profile {

    }
}
```

Note that I prefer to use `clazz.cast()` instead of a dirty cast, because it is safer and you don't have to use `@SuppressWarnings`

Answer (score 0):

This, `stack = (T[]) new Object[size];` isn't allowed. Because of [type-erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the type `T` *is* `Object` at run-time. However, you can pass in the `class` type to your **generic** class, that will allow you to use [`Array.newInstance(Class, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).

```
static <E> E[] makeAnArray(Class<E> cls, int length) {
    return (E[]) Array.newInstance(cls, length);
}
```